# issue of converting .eps file to .png file with gs

Tags: ghostscript

I tried to use the command to convert the .eps file to .png file

```
gs -dSAFER -dEPSCrop -r300 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o test.png test.eps
```

But the figure has the wrong bbox, just like viewing it in the letter size in gv.

If I used

```
gs -dEPSCrop -r300 -sDEVICE=bbox -o test.png test.eps
```

gs is able to find the correct bbox as (well close, the exact BoudingBox in the .eps file is "21 54 1101 558"):

> %%BoundingBox: 35 62 1083 554
>
> %%HiResBoundingBox: 35.040001 62.400002 1082.640041 553.440021

Is there something I miss to convert the .eps file to .png file with the bbox? Thank you.

Comment: You haven't said what version of Ghostscript you are using and to be honest, nobody is likely going to be able to help you without seeing the original EPS file. You are not comparing like with like when you run the bbox device. The bbox device **finds** the bounding box by rendering the content, and then reports that size. The EPSCrop switch **uses** the size given by the EPS file. My guess would be (without seeing the file) that there is something wrong with the BoundingBox comment in the EPS.

Comment: You are correct that there's something wrong with the .eps file generated by the software. The issue is fixed after using another software to generate the .eps files.